# Splitting a column with list of tuples into a seperate columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a dataframe which has a shopping_cart column in the following format:
the first element of the tuple is the item ordered, and the second element is the quantity ordered for such item: for example:[('Candle Inferno', 1), ('iAssist Line', 2)] implies 'Candle Inferno' was bought once and 'iAssist Line' was bought twice.

```
[('Candle Inferno', 1), ('iAssist Line', 2)]
[('Olivia x460', 1), ('Candle Inferno', 1),('Alcon 10', 2)]
[('Lucent 330S', 1), ('pearTV', 1), ('Universe Note', 2), ('Olivia x460', 2)]
```

I have the following code in place which is intended to separate the items and quantity for example:

```
item_1    qty_item_1         item_2        qty_item_2
Alcon 10       1         Candle Inferno       2
```

Code:

```
item_1=[]
item_2=[]
item_3=[]
import re
for i in range(0,1):
    item1=str(list_of_items[i].split(',')[0].split(','))
    item2=str(list_of_items[i].split(',')[2].split(','))
    item3=str(list_of_items[i].split(',')[4].split(','))
    item_1.append((re.sub(r'[^\w]',' ',item1).strip()))
    item_2.append((re.sub(r'[^\w]',' ',item2).strip()))
    item_3.append((re.sub(r'[^\w]',' ',item3).strip()))
```

The above works to split item names: first item(item_1),second item(item_2), however, this is too repetitive. Even if I try to create a function, the function throws an error and also fails if the number of tuples are more than 3 or 4

Is there any better way to solve this?

Comment: What should the end result be?

Comment: I've made changes to the question. Pls let me know if it needs further clarification

Answer (score 0):

```
def pretty_printer(l):
    header = "|".join(["item_%d\tquantity_%d" % (index+1, index+1) for index, _ in numerate(l)])
    items = "|".join(["%s\t%d" % (i[0], i[1]) for i in l])
    print(header)
    print(items)

    
l1 = [('Candle Inferno', 1), ('iAssist Line', 2)]
l2 = [('Olivia x460', 1), ('Candle Inferno', 1), ('Alcon 10', 2)]
l3 = [('Lucent 330S', 1), ('pearTV', 1), ('Universe Note', 2), ('Olivia x460', 2)]
    
pretty_printer(l1)
pretty_printer(l2)
pretty_printer(l3)
```

Output:

```
item_1  quantity_1|item_2   quantity_2
Candle Inferno  1|iAssist Line  2
item_1  quantity_1|item_2   quantity_2|item_3   quantity_3
Olivia x460 1|Candle Inferno    1|Alcon 10  2
item_1  quantity_1|item_2   quantity_2|item_3   quantity_3|item_4   quantity_4
Lucent 330S 1|pearTV    1|Universe Note 2|Olivia x460   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal seems to be to "*separate items and quantity*" the following might help.

I suppose, but it's not clear from your question, that `list_of_items` looks like (your second example):

```
list_of_items = [('Olivia x460', 1), ('Candle Inferno', 1), ('Alcon 10', 2)]
```

To separate the items from the quantities you could do the following:

```
items, quantities = zip(*list_of_items)
```

The result looks like:

```
items: ('Olivia x460', 'Candle Inferno', 'Alcon 10')
quantities: (1, 1, 2)
```

If you want to do that for the whole list

```
orders = [
    [('Candle Inferno', 1), ('iAssist Line', 2)],
    [('Olivia x460', 1), ('Candle Inferno', 1),('Alcon 10', 2)],
    [('Lucent 330S', 1), ('pearTV', 1), ('Universe Note', 2), ('Olivia x460', 2)],
]
```

consolidated, then something like this might work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

orders_consolidated = defaultdict(int)
for order in orders:
    for item, quantity in order:
        orders_consolidated[item] += quantity

items, quantities = zip(*orders_consolidated.items())
```

The result looks like:

```
items: ('Candle Inferno', 'iAssist Line', 'Olivia x460', 'Alcon 10', 'Lucent 330S', 'pearTV', 'Universe Note')
quantities: (2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2)
```